# How to prevent MapStruct from creating entity if the source is null?

Tags: java, mapstruct

Is there a way to prevent MapStruct from creating an object if the source is null?

Existing answers I've found explain how to do it with the object but not in a nested path. Here is an example.

The mapper

```
@Mapping(target = "manufacturer.id", source = "manufacturerId")
CarEntity toEntity(CarDTO carDto);
```

The generated code, in comments what Mapstruct misses

```
protected ManuFacturerEntity carDTOToCarEntity(CarDTO carDto) {
    if ( carDto == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    // what I'd like mapstruct to generate
    if (cardDto.manufacturerId == null) {
        return null;
    }

    ManufactureurEntity manufacturerEntity = new ManufacturerEntity();
    manufactureurEntity.id = carDto.manufacturerId;
    return panneaumanufacturerEntity;
}
```

I know I probably can do it with `@BeforeMapping` but it doesn't just feel the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

after i searched a lot.i found https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1306

and in this issue they said you should use this code:

```
@Mapping(source = "id", target = "object.id")
    Target toModel(Source source);

    @AfterMapping
    default void after(final @MappingTarget Target target, final Source source) {
        if(source.getId() == null) {
            target.setObject(null);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the mapping target to `manufacturer` and define a default method for mapping the `manufacturerId` to the `ManufacturerEntity` object that creates the object only if `manufacturerId` is not `null`.

```java
@Mapping(target = "manufacturer", source = "manufacturerId")
CarEntity toEntity(CarDTO carDto);

default ManufacturerEntity mapManufacturerId(Long manufacturerId){
    if (manufacturerId == null) return null;
    ManufacturerEntity manufacturerEntity = new ManufacturerEntity();
    manufacturerEntity.id = manufacturerId;
    return manufacturerEntity;
}
```

Comment: Probably just add `abstract ManufacturerEntity mapManufacturerId(Long id)` should be enough to instruct MapStruct to map automatically a `Long -> ManufacturerEntity`

Comment: Good idea but it still create a new instance without checking nullity first